# I want to edit PDF invoice payment method in magento2.3

Tags: magento2, php

I want to change the position of payment and shipping method position. I want to move this block below grand total. I tried a lot but not working for me.
[image: ino]

[image: Now updated Version]

This is updated code result.

Comment: You want to this type https://prnt.sc/rx1eou ??

Comment: @mohit   Yes but grand total should be outside the rectangle box.

Comment: this is image box not a rectangle . but payment  method and shipping method showing without any box.

Comment: @mohit I need paymebt mwthod and shippong method below grand total same as it is. No change in design. I want to display this block after total.

Comment: @mohit How are you displaying it in below grand total.

Comment: this type showing in my project  check Please https://prnt.sc/rx5nb6

Comment: Can you share me your code so i will try this @mohit ?

Comment: Please  Check my answer.

Comment: I will try this and then let you know

Comment: @mohit How can add lines and header box in your code to display like default block. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1):

1. We need to to override the class.

**app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference type="Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice" for="Vendor\Module\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice"/>
</config>
```

2. Create Invoice.php file in below path 
   **app/code/Vendor/Module/Model/Order/Pdf/Invoice.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Order\Pdf;

class Invoice extends \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice
{
    public function getPdf($invoices = [])
    {
        $this->_beforeGetPdf();
        $this->_initRenderer('invoice');

        $pdf = new \Zend_Pdf();
        $this->_setPdf($pdf);
        $style = new \Zend_Pdf_Style();
        $this->_setFontBold($style, 10);

        foreach ($invoices as $invoice) {
            if ($invoice->getStoreId()) {
                $this->_localeResolver->emulate($invoice->getStoreId());
                $this->_storeManager->setCurrentStore($invoice->getStoreId());
            }
            $page = $this->newPage();
            $order = $invoice->getOrder();
            /* Add image */
            $this->insertLogo($page, $invoice->getStore());
            /* Add address */
            $this->insertAddress($page, $invoice->getStore());
            /* Add head */
            $this->insertOrder(
                $page,
                $order,
                $this->_scopeConfig->isSetFlag(
                    self::XML_PATH_SALES_PDF_INVOICE_PUT_ORDER_ID,
                    \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                    $order->getStoreId()
                )
            );
            /* Add document text and number */
            $this->insertDocumentNumber($page, __('Invoice # ') . $invoice->getIncrementId());
            /* Add table */
            $this->_drawHeader($page);
            /* Add body */
            foreach ($invoice->getAllItems() as $item) {
                if ($item->getOrderItem()->getParentItem()) {
                    continue;
                }
                /* Draw item */
                $this->_drawItem($item, $page, $order);
                $page = end($pdf->pages);
            }
            /* Add totals */
            $this->insertTotals($page, $invoice);
            $this->insertPaymentInfo($page,
                $order,
                $this->_scopeConfig->isSetFlag(
                    self::XML_PATH_SALES_PDF_INVOICE_PUT_ORDER_ID,
                    \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                    $order->getStoreId()
                ));
            if ($invoice->getStoreId()) {
                $this->_localeResolver->revert();
            }
        }
        $this->_afterGetPdf();
        return $pdf;
    }

    protected function insertPaymentInfo(&$page, $obj, $putOrderId = true)
    {
        if ($obj instanceof \Magento\Sales\Model\Order) {
            $shipment = null;
            $order = $obj;
        } elseif ($obj instanceof \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Shipment) {
            $shipment = $obj;
            $order = $shipment->getOrder();
        }

        $this->y = $this->y ? $this->y : 815;
        $top = $this->y;

        /* Calculate blocks info */

        /* Payment */
        $paymentInfo = $this->_paymentData->getInfoBlock($order->getPayment())->setIsSecureMode(true)->toPdf();
        $paymentInfo = htmlspecialchars_decode($paymentInfo, ENT_QUOTES);
        $payment = explode('{{pdf_row_separator}}', $paymentInfo);
        foreach ($payment as $key => $value) {
            if (strip_tags(trim($value)) == '') {
                unset($payment[$key]);
            }
        }
        reset($payment);

        /* Shipping Address and Method */
        if (!$order->getIsVirtual()) {
            $shippingMethod = $order->getShippingDescription();
        }

        $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(0));
        $this->_setFontBold($page, 12);

        if (!$order->getIsVirtual()) {
            //$page->drawText(__('Ship to:'), 285, $top - 15, 'UTF-8');
        } else {
            $page->drawText(__('Payment Method:'), 285, $top - 15, 'UTF-8');
        }

        $this->y = $top;

        if (!$order->getIsVirtual()) {

            $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_Rgb(0.93, 0.92, 0.92));
            $page->setLineWidth(0.5);
            $page->drawRectangle(25, $this->y, 275, $this->y - 25);
            $page->drawRectangle(275, $this->y, 570, $this->y - 25);

            $this->y -= 15;
            $this->_setFontBold($page, 12);
            $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(0));
            $page->drawText(__('Payment Method'), 35, $this->y, 'UTF-8');
            $page->drawText(__('Shipping Method:'), 285, $this->y, 'UTF-8');

            $this->y -= 10;
            $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(1));

            $this->_setFontRegular($page, 10);
            $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(0));

            $paymentLeft = 35;
            $yPayments = $this->y - 15;
        } else {
            $yPayments = $this->y;
            $paymentLeft = 285;
        }

        foreach ($payment as $value) {
            if (trim($value) != '') {
                //Printing "Payment Method" lines
                $value = preg_replace('/<br[^>]*>/i', "\n", $value);
                foreach ($this->string->split($value, 45, true, true) as $_value) {
                    $page->drawText(strip_tags(trim($_value)), $paymentLeft, $yPayments, 'UTF-8');
                    $yPayments -= 15;
                }
            }
        }

        if ($order->getIsVirtual()) {
            // replacement of Shipments-Payments rectangle block
            $yPayments = min($this->y, $yPayments);
            $page->drawLine(25, $top - 25, 25, $yPayments);
            $page->drawLine(570, $top - 25, 570, $yPayments);
            $page->drawLine(25, $yPayments, 570, $yPayments);

            $this->y = $yPayments - 15;
        } else {
            $topMargin = 15;
            $methodStartY = $this->y;
            $this->y -= 15;

            foreach ($this->string->split($shippingMethod, 45, true, true) as $_value) {
                $page->drawText(strip_tags(trim($_value)), 285, $this->y, 'UTF-8');
                $this->y -= 15;
            }

            $yShipments = $this->y;
            $totalShippingChargesText = "(" . __(
                    'Total Shipping Charges'
                ) . " " . $order->formatPriceTxt(
                    $order->getShippingAmount()
                ) . ")";

            $page->drawText($totalShippingChargesText, 285, $yShipments - $topMargin, 'UTF-8');
            $yShipments -= $topMargin + 10;

            $tracks = [];
            if ($shipment) {
                $tracks = $shipment->getAllTracks();
            }
            if (count($tracks)) {
                $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_Rgb(0.93, 0.92, 0.92));
                $page->setLineWidth(0.5);
                $page->drawRectangle(285, $yShipments, 510, $yShipments - 10);
                $page->drawLine(400, $yShipments, 400, $yShipments - 10);
                //$page->drawLine(510, $yShipments, 510, $yShipments - 10);

                $this->_setFontRegular($page, 9);
                $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(0));
                //$page->drawText(__('Carrier'), 290, $yShipments - 7 , 'UTF-8');
                $page->drawText(__('Title'), 290, $yShipments - 7, 'UTF-8');
                $page->drawText(__('Number'), 410, $yShipments - 7, 'UTF-8');

                $yShipments -= 20;
                $this->_setFontRegular($page, 8);
                foreach ($tracks as $track) {
                    $maxTitleLen = 45;
                    $endOfTitle = strlen($track->getTitle()) > $maxTitleLen ? '...' : '';
                    $truncatedTitle = substr($track->getTitle(), 0, $maxTitleLen) . $endOfTitle;
                    $page->drawText($truncatedTitle, 292, $yShipments, 'UTF-8');
                    $page->drawText($track->getNumber(), 410, $yShipments, 'UTF-8');
                    $yShipments -= $topMargin - 5;
                }
            } else {
                $yShipments -= $topMargin - 5;
            }

            $currentY = min($yPayments, $yShipments);

            // replacement of Shipments-Payments rectangle block
            $page->drawLine(25, $methodStartY, 25, $currentY);
            //left
            $page->drawLine(25, $currentY, 570, $currentY);
            //bottom
            $page->drawLine(570, $currentY, 570, $methodStartY);
            //right

            $this->y = $currentY;
            $this->y -= 15;
        }
    }

    protected function insertOrder(&$page, $obj, $putOrderId = true)
    {
        if ($obj instanceof \Magento\Sales\Model\Order) {
            $shipment = null;
            $order = $obj;
        } elseif ($obj instanceof \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Shipment) {
            $shipment = $obj;
            $order = $shipment->getOrder();
        }

        $this->y = $this->y ? $this->y : 815;
        $top = $this->y;

        $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(0.45));
        $page->setLineColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(0.45));
        $page->drawRectangle(25, $top, 570, $top - 55);
        $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(1));
        $this->setDocHeaderCoordinates([25, $top, 570, $top - 55]);
        $this->_setFontRegular($page, 10);

        if ($putOrderId) {
            $page->drawText(__('Order # ') . $order->getRealOrderId(), 35, $top -= 30, 'UTF-8');
        }
        $page->drawText(
            __('Order Date: ') .
            $this->_localeDate->formatDate(
                $this->_localeDate->scopeDate(
                    $order->getStore(),
                    $order->getCreatedAt(),
                    true
                ),
                \IntlDateFormatter::MEDIUM,
                false
            ),
            35,
            $top -= 15,
            'UTF-8'
        );

        $top -= 10;
        $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_Rgb(0.93, 0.92, 0.92));
        $page->setLineColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(0.5));
        $page->setLineWidth(0.5);
        $page->drawRectangle(25, $top, 275, $top - 25);
        $page->drawRectangle(275, $top, 570, $top - 25);

        /* Calculate blocks info */

        /* Billing Address */
        $billingAddress = $this->_formatAddress($this->addressRenderer->format($order->getBillingAddress(), 'pdf'));

        /* Payment */
        $paymentInfo = $this->_paymentData->getInfoBlock($order->getPayment())->setIsSecureMode(true)->toPdf();
        $paymentInfo = htmlspecialchars_decode($paymentInfo, ENT_QUOTES);
        $payment = explode('{{pdf_row_separator}}', $paymentInfo);
        foreach ($payment as $key => $value) {
            if (strip_tags(trim($value)) == '') {
                unset($payment[$key]);
            }
        }
        reset($payment);

        /* Shipping Address and Method */
        if (!$order->getIsVirtual()) {
            /* Shipping Address */
            $shippingAddress = $this->_formatAddress($this->addressRenderer->format($order->getShippingAddress(), 'pdf'));
            $shippingMethod = $order->getShippingDescription();
        }

        $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(0));
        $this->_setFontBold($page, 12);
        $page->drawText(__('Sold to:'), 35, $top - 15, 'UTF-8');

        if (!$order->getIsVirtual()) {
            $page->drawText(__('Ship to:'), 285, $top - 15, 'UTF-8');
        } else {
            $page->drawText(__('Payment Method:'), 285, $top - 15, 'UTF-8');
        }

        $addressesHeight = $this->_calcAddressHeight($billingAddress);
        if (isset($shippingAddress)) {
            $addressesHeight = max($addressesHeight, $this->_calcAddressHeight($shippingAddress));
        }

        $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(1));
        $page->drawRectangle(25, $top - 25, 570, $top - 33 - $addressesHeight);
        $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(0));
        $this->_setFontRegular($page, 10);
        $this->y = $top - 40;
        $addressesStartY = $this->y;

        foreach ($billingAddress as $value) {
            if ($value !== '') {
                $text = [];
                foreach ($this->string->split($value, 45, true, true) as $_value) {
                    $text[] = $_value;
                }
                foreach ($text as $part) {
                    $page->drawText(strip_tags(ltrim($part)), 35, $this->y, 'UTF-8');
                    $this->y -= 15;
                }
            }
        }

        $addressesEndY = $this->y;

        if (!$order->getIsVirtual()) {
            $this->y = $addressesStartY;
            foreach ($shippingAddress as $value) {
                if ($value !== '') {
                    $text = [];
                    foreach ($this->string->split($value, 45, true, true) as $_value) {
                        $text[] = $_value;
                    }
                    foreach ($text as $part) {
                        $page->drawText(strip_tags(ltrim($part)), 285, $this->y, 'UTF-8');
                        $this->y -= 15;
                    }
                }
            }

            $addressesEndY = min($addressesEndY, $this->y);
            $this->y = $addressesEndY;

            /*$page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_Rgb(0.93, 0.92, 0.92));
            $page->setLineWidth(0.5);
            $page->drawRectangle(25, $this->y, 275, $this->y - 25);
            $page->drawRectangle(275, $this->y, 570, $this->y - 25);

            $this->y -= 15;
            $this->_setFontBold($page, 12);
            $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(0));
            $page->drawText(__('Payment Method'), 35, $this->y, 'UTF-8');
            $page->drawText(__('Shipping Method:'), 285, $this->y, 'UTF-8');*/

            $this->y -= 10;
            $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(1));

            $this->_setFontRegular($page, 10);
            $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(0));

            $paymentLeft = 35;
            $yPayments = $this->y - 15;
        } else {
            $yPayments = $addressesStartY;
            $paymentLeft = 285;
        }


        if ($order->getIsVirtual()) {
            // replacement of Shipments-Payments rectangle block
            $yPayments = min($addressesEndY, $yPayments);
            $page->drawLine(25, $top - 25, 25, $yPayments);
            $page->drawLine(570, $top - 25, 570, $yPayments);
            $page->drawLine(25, $yPayments, 570, $yPayments);

            $this->y = $yPayments - 15;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`AbstractPdf.php` file override you custom module and insert this function `protected function insertOrder`.

```
protected function insertOrder(&$page, $obj, $putOrderId = true)
    {
        if ($obj instanceof \Magento\Sales\Model\Order) {
            $shipment = null;
            $order = $obj;
        } elseif ($obj instanceof \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Shipment) {
            $shipment = $obj;
            $order = $shipment->getOrder();
        }

        $this->y = $this->y ? $this->y : 815;
        $top = $this->y;

        $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(0.45));
        $page->setLineColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(0.45));
        $page->drawRectangle(25, $top, 570, $top - 65);
        $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(1));
        $this->setDocHeaderCoordinates([25, $top, 570, $top - 55]);
        $this->_setFontRegular($page, 10);

        if ($putOrderId) {
            $page->drawText(__('Order # ') . $order->getRealOrderId(), 35, $top -= 30, 'UTF-8');
        }
        $page->drawText(
            __('Order Date: ') .
            $this->_localeDate->formatDate(
                $this->_localeDate->scopeDate(
                    $order->getStore(),
                    $order->getCreatedAt(),
                    true
                ),
                \IntlDateFormatter::MEDIUM,
                false
            ),
            35,
            $top -= 15,
            'UTF-8'
        );
        

        $top -= 10;
        $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_Rgb(0.93, 0.92, 0.92));
        $page->setLineColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(0.5));
        $page->setLineWidth(0.5);
        $page->drawRectangle(25, $top, 275, $top - 25);
        $page->drawRectangle(275, $top, 570, $top - 25);

        /* Calculate blocks info */

        /* Billing Address */
        $billingAddress = $this->_formatAddress($this->addressRenderer->format($order->getBillingAddress(), 'pdf'));

        /* Payment */
        $paymentInfo = $this->_paymentData->getInfoBlock($order->getPayment())->setIsSecureMode(true)->toPdf();
        $paymentInfo = htmlspecialchars_decode($paymentInfo, ENT_QUOTES);
        $payment = explode('{{pdf_row_separator}}', $paymentInfo);
        foreach ($payment as $key => $value) {
            if (strip_tags(trim($value)) == '') {
                unset($payment[$key]);
            }
        }
        reset($payment);

        /* Shipping Address and Method */
        if (!$order->getIsVirtual()) {
            /* Shipping Address */
            $shippingAddress = $this->_formatAddress($this->addressRenderer->format($order->getShippingAddress(), 'pdf'));
            $shippingMethod = $order->getShippingDescription();
        }

        $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(0));
        $this->_setFontBold($page, 12);
        $page->drawText(__('Sold to:'), 35, $top - 15, 'UTF-8');

        if (!$order->getIsVirtual()) {
            $page->drawText(__('Ship to:'), 285, $top - 15, 'UTF-8');
        } else {
            $page->drawText(__('Payment Method:'), 285, $top - 15, 'UTF-8');
        }

        $addressesHeight = $this->_calcAddressHeight($billingAddress);
        if (isset($shippingAddress)) {
            $addressesHeight = max($addressesHeight, $this->_calcAddressHeight($shippingAddress));
        }

        $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(1));
        $page->drawRectangle(25, $top - 25, 570, $top - 33 - $addressesHeight);
        $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(0));
        $this->_setFontRegular($page, 10);
        $this->y = $top - 40;
        $addressesStartY = $this->y;

        foreach ($billingAddress as $value) {
            if ($value !== '') {
                $text = [];
                foreach ($this->string->split($value, 40, true, true) as $_value) {
                    $text[] = $_value;
                }
                foreach ($text as $part) {
                    $page->drawText(strip_tags(ltrim($part)), 35, $this->y, 'UTF-8');
                    $this->y -= 15;
                }
            }
        }

        $addressesEndY = $this->y;

        if (!$order->getIsVirtual()) {
            $this->y = $addressesStartY;
            foreach ($shippingAddress as $value) {
                if ($value !== '') {
                    $text = [];
                    foreach ($this->string->split($value, 40, true, true) as $_value) {
                        $text[] = $_value;
                    }
                    foreach ($text as $part) {
                        $page->drawText(strip_tags(ltrim($part)), 285, $this->y, 'UTF-8');
                        $this->y -= 15;
                    }
                }
            }

            $addressesEndY = min($addressesEndY, $this->y);
            $this->y = $addressesEndY;
            


            $this->y -= 15;

            $this->y -= 10;
            $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(1));

            $this->_setFontRegular($page, 10);
            $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(0));

            $paymentLeft = 35;
            $yPayments = $this->y - 15;
        } else {
            $yPayments = $addressesStartY;
            $paymentLeft = 285;
        }

        foreach ($payment as $value) {
            if (trim($value) != '') {
                //Printing "Payment Method" lines
                $value = preg_replace('/<br[^>]*>/i', "\n", $value);
                foreach ($this->string->split($value, 45, true, true) as $_value) {
                    $page->drawText(strip_tags(trim($_value)), 35, $top - 300, 'UTF-8');
                    $yPayments -= 15;
                }
            }
        }

        if ($order->getIsVirtual()) {
            // replacement of Shipments-Payments rectangle block
            // $yPayments = min($addressesEndY, $yPayments);
            // $page->drawLine(25, $top - 25, 25, $yPayments);
            // $page->drawLine(570, $top - 25, 570, $yPayments);
            // $page->drawLine(25, $yPayments, 570, $yPayments);

            $this->y = $yPayments - 15;
        } else {
            $topMargin = 15;
            $methodStartY = $this->y;
            $this->y -= 15;

            foreach ($this->string->split($shippingMethod, 45, true, true) as $_value) {
                $page->drawText(strip_tags(trim($_value)),  285, $top - 300, 'UTF-8');
                $this->y -= 15;
            }

            $yShipments = $this->y;
            $totalShippingChargesText = "(" . __(
                    'Total Shipping Charges'
                ) . " " . $order->formatPriceTxt(
                    $order->getShippingAmount()
                ) . ")";

            $page->drawText($totalShippingChargesText, 285, $top - 320, 'UTF-8');
            $yShipments -= $topMargin + 10;


            $this->y -= -45;
            
            $tracks = [];
            if ($shipment) {
                $tracks = $shipment->getAllTracks();
            }
            if (count($tracks)) {
                $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_Rgb(0.93, 0.92, 0.92));
                $page->setLineWidth(0.5);
                $page->drawRectangle(285, $yShipments, 510, $yShipments - 10);
                $page->drawLine(400, $yShipments, 400, $yShipments - 10);
                //$page->drawLine(510, $yShipments, 510, $yShipments - 10);

                $this->_setFontRegular($page, 9);
                $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(0));
                //$page->drawText(__('Carrier'), 290, $yShipments - 7 , 'UTF-8');
                $page->drawText(__('Title'), 290, $yShipments - 7, 'UTF-8');
                $page->drawText(__('Number'), 410, $yShipments - 7, 'UTF-8');

                $yShipments = 20;
                $this->_setFontRegular($page, 8);
                foreach ($tracks as $track) {
                    $maxTitleLen = 45;
                    $endOfTitle = strlen($track->getTitle()) > $maxTitleLen ? '...' : '';
                    $truncatedTitle = substr($track->getTitle(), 0, $maxTitleLen) . $endOfTitle;
                    $page->drawText($truncatedTitle, 292, $yShipments, 'UTF-8');
                    $page->drawText($track->getNumber(), 410, $yShipments, 'UTF-8');
                    $yShipments -= $topMargin - 5;
                }
            } else {
                $yShipments -= $topMargin - 5;
            }
            
            $top -= 263;
            $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_Rgb(0.93, 0.92, 0.92));
            $page->setLineWidth(0.5);
            $page->drawRectangle(25, $top, 275, $top - 25);
            $page->drawRectangle(275, $top, 570, $top - 25);

            //$top -= 15;
            $this->_setFontBold($page, 12);
            $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(0));
            $page->drawText(__('Payment Method:'), 35, $top - 16, 'UTF-8');
            $page->drawText(__('Shipping Method:'), 285, $top - 16, 'UTF-8');           
            $page->drawRectangle(25, $top, 570, $top - 80,'UTF-8');
            
        }
    }
```

Output :-

[image]

You Don't know how to override Abstract Pdf.php so let me know.I will explain briefly.

Thanks.

Comment: you helpful answer after checked so accept answer..

Comment: check my update answer..

Comment: @mohig didn't get where to add 2nd part of code. In the last two brackets, what do you mean where?

Comment: Check my second code in my answer

Comment: Where i have to put your second code ?

Comment: else {
                $yShipments -= $topMargin - 5;
            }
after this

Comment: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '}' in at last line of 2ndcode.

Comment: i have second full code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106588/discussion-between-yousaf-and-mohit-patel).

Comment: I updated my output in question. Check that its all messed up.

Comment: Hello @Yousaf Please check my final code and let me know this useful or not ??

Comment: Hello @Yousaf my final update answer helpful or not ??