# How to add a Link in Shipment PDF?

Tags: magento2, pdf, link

[image]I'm creating a PDF file with a link and I need to open the link in a new window. How can I do that?

Comment: Check this for reference https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/282464/84221

Comment: can you please add code

Comment: @RkRathod I didn't have code, I just have this mockup and want to know that how to apply link in PDF