# Magento 2.4.2 : How to add page number in footer of Invoice pdf?

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, page, footer, invoice-pdf

Can anybody tell me how we can add Page numbers to each page of the invoice pdf?

https://nimb.ws/rcNG8B

I want to add the page numbers in the footer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the number of pages in the pdf using `$pdf->pages` and loop through them increasing the index and rendering them at the same time. Something as follows;

```
$number_pages = sizeof($pdf->pages);

foreach($pdf->pages AS $key => $page) {
    $page->setFillColor(new Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(0));
    $page->drawText(($key + 1) . "/$number_pages", 540, 15, 'UTF-8');
}
```

Comment: Where do i need to write this code?

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/282456/how-to-edit-invoice-pdf-in-magento-2-3

Comment: Thanx. this worked for me